# How a tenure-track candidate should/may answer the question "How do you view your role in the faculty development process?"

Tags: tenure-track, assistant-professor

Faculty members (often!) gradually develop from inexperienced rookies to experienced scholars. In my view, the impact of a faculty member on the development of other faculty members is practically possible if those colleagues are less experienced than that faculty member. But, it seems the question "How do you view your role in the faculty development process?" is often asked from tenure-track candidates in search committee interviews. In such scenarios, what can a meaningful answer to this question be?

Comment: Well, have you thought about it? What do you think your role is/should be? I don't think these sorts of things are easy to lie about - if you haven't thought about it, you're likely to sound foolish when asked follow up questions.

Comment: I think I would respond by asking them to clarify the question.  Do they mean how you would help other faculty develop, or how you would develop yourself?

Comment: @NateEldredge: The answer to the latter interpretation is fairly straightforward. But, what if the former interpretation is the one they intend?

Comment: @BryanKrause: Your comment makes me wonder whether or not you have read the body of the question!

Comment: I'm trying to be constructive here: you are asking how you should answer a question that *asks you for your opinion about your role*. If you have an opinion, why wouldn't you start there? By asking how you should answer the question, it seems like you view this as a game to play rather than an earnest question about your fit for this position. Do you have experience with mentorship? What do you think about that experience and how it will shape your future mentorship? That's what the question is asking. Why should you answer with someone else's thoughts rather than your own?